# VMWare vCenter Solutions and Applications Icon Missing - Update Manager

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-server, vcenter

I just recently installed vCenter server and the update manager and in the docs it says that I need to go to the 'Solutions and Applications' icon on the homepage. But it is not there. I have checked that the service is up and running and that the update manager plugin is installed in vCenter. I also can go to the hosts and in the monitor tab and see update manager stuff, but no way to do any actual updates.

Tried IE and Chrome, attempting FF right now.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Getting these errors in my debugging console in chrome:

```
csd_api_connection.js:73 WebSocket connection to 'wss://vmware-localhost:8093/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_WEAK_SERVER_EPHEMERAL_DH_KEY
csd_api_connection.js:73 WebSocket connection to 'wss://vmware-localhost:8093/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Looks like the problem is in the `csd_api_connection.js` on line 73. What is it trying to connect to?

**EDIT:**

So I fixed the errors above by opening the web client in a vm of windows 7 with IE10, but still not seeing the `Solutions and Applications` icon on the homepage.